# Can I compile two classes that need each other?

Tags: java, import, cyclic-dependency

I am making a package in which there are two classes that import each other.

Will it work? The thing I am doing is like this:

```
package com;
import com.B;

class A {

     private B b;

}
```

```
package com;
import com.A;

class B {
    private A a;
}
```

And if this will work, are there any senario or cases similar to this that might not work? (Like having a constructor that makes object of the other class in both the classes, or something else?)

Thanks for helping!

Comment: This situation is known as a "circular dependency" and there are known solutions for it. The exact solution will depend on the reason each class needs to depend on the other and what each class needs from the other. Generally, solutions call for an interface to be used to break the dependency cycle.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work, which you can see if you try it yourself. It's generally best to avoid circular references, though, as they complicate the design.

It's easy to cause infinite loops in your code if you're not careful. For instance, if you call the constructor of the other class on both sides, it will compile just fine but will end in a java.lang.StackOverflowError; same with any (combination) of calls that go back and forth, directly or indirectly.

I've expanded your example a little to demonstrate that you can compile and run it just fine.

```
package com;
public class A {
    private B b;

    public A() {
        b = new B();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        (new A()).print();
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(b.getText());
    }
}
```

```
package com;
public class B {
    private A a;

    public B() {
        //a = new A();
    }

    public String getText() {
        return "Hello, world";
    }
}
```